# improving algorithm to be faster - scanning image from file

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, bitmap

My code here works but takes a couple seconds longer and with larger files it takes longer and i wanted to know if anyone can take a look over what i have and suggest any kind of improvement that will help make this faster.

Purpose:

This is to scan a pdf file and search for the bitmap image of a QR code and it will return the code for it (decode)

```
private void ScanQRPdf(string imagePath)
    {
        foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(imagePath))
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(item).ToLower() == ".png")
            {
                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(imagePath);
                try
                {
                    QRCodeDecoder decoder = new QRCodeDecoder();
                    String decodedString = decoder.decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(b));
                    rtbpdfData.Text += decodedString + "\n";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }

 static void AddQRTag(PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics gfx, int xPosition, int yPosition, string QRdata, string HRdata)
    {
        gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.White, xPosition, yPosition, xPosition + 55, yPosition + 85);

        PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage xImage =
            PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(BuildQR(QRdata.ToUpper(), 3,
                                            QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.ALPHA_NUMERIC, 2, QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.M));
        gfx.DrawImage(xImage, xPosition + 5, yPosition + 5, xImage.PixelWidth * .8, xImage.PixelWidth * .8);


        XFont font = new XFont("OCR B", 6);
        XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
        tf.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Left;


        XRect layout = new XRect(xPosition + 5, yPosition + 55, 55, 30);
        tf.DrawString(HRdata.ToUpper(), font, XBrushes.Black, layout, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
    }
```

Comment: The slow code is probably in the `QRCodeDecoder` class. There's not a lot you can do from here.

Comment: Something to ask yourself: Does the decoder dispose of your `Bitmap`s?

Comment: 1 suggestion: remove the `catch{}`.

Comment: Can you post the link to `QRCodeDecoder` source code? (I am presuming that you're using an O/S library)

Comment: Obtain a profiler. It will tell you where the bottleneck is. Guessing is usually a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, if you only need to process the top-left corner of your image, you can extract that part of your image using `Bitmap.Clone`.

In that case, I would refactor your code to something like this:

```
private void ScanQRPdf(string imagePath)
{
    foreach (var decodedString in DecodeAllImagesInFolder(imagePath))
    {
        rtbpdfData.Text += decodedString + "\n";
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<string> DecodeAllImagesInFolder(string imagePath)
{
    foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(imagePath, "*.png"))
    {
        using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(imagePath))
        {
            yield return DecodeTopLeftCorner(b);
        }
    }
}

private static string DecodeTopLeftCorner(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    using (var topLeft = bitmap.Clone(rect, bitmap.PixelFormat))
    {
        return new QRCodeDecoder().decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(topLeft));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just trying this out and i got "Invalid number of Finder Pattern detected" i am debugging to see the source.

Comment: @BB987: note that the rectangle size I chose is completely arbitrary. You should probably check whether it crops the entire code. And also, you were swallowing exceptions earlier (as @Henk mentioned in comments), which is usually a bad practice. It's possible that the `decode` method throws this exception whenever it doesn't find a code, but I cannot tell without looking at its source.

Comment: I see ya i am doing some alteration and seeing. Also just came to mind . since i am only looking at a single file that is passed in by the user do i still have to have a directory to get all files? Can't i just use that single file?

Comment: @BB987: sure, why not? There is no need to use `Directory.GetFiles` if you already know the filename.

Comment: so would i be save in removing the foreach loop and inserting the imagepath into the using statement? `using(Bitmap b = new Bitmap(imagePath)`?

Comment: @BB987: yes, that's what you should do.

Answer (score 3):

In the code, which you past everything is ok. The problem must be in QRCodeDecoder.decode function. If you are scanning image pixel by pixel, via Bitmap.GetPixel function, it will waste a lot of time. Better way will be to use unsafe code and convert bitmap to BitmapData.

Comment: +1 If this is an open source library, then `GetPixel` is probably OP's best bet (unless he/she wants to devise a better algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for the info - is there a way to only scan/check the corners of a file for a bitmap ?

Comment: Yes, sure. If you know the width and height of the image (you can get them from Bitmap Object), then you can scan only corners. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx
You can change the part of loop in this way:
//upper corner
for (int counter = 2; counter < bmpData.Stride; counter += 3)
                rgbValues[counter] = 255;
//left corner
for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += bmpData.Stride)
                rgbValues[counter] = 255;
And continue the same way to get bottom and right corners.

Comment: By the way 
rgbValues[counter] - is red color;
rgbValues[counter+1] - is green color;
rgbValues[counter+2] - is blur color;

Comment: Thanks for all the info!! i am looking online now and will let you know. Just to be clear the corners you are talking about are they the corners for the image or the file? I want to serach the corners of a scanned pdf file for a bitmap image.

Comment: @BB987 In that case you probably want to use the [Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944(v=vs.100).aspx) method to clone portions of your image into 4 separate bitmaps, and then process them individually. Btw, don't forget to dispose your initial bitmap, and all subsequently created ones, as they usually consume lots of memory.

Comment: @Groo - ok i am trying to wrap my head around this. I just added the method i used to create and place the qr code above. in the topLeft. how can i use that to write a method to look at the top left corner of the file?

Comment: @BB987: what's a "top left corner" for you? Is that a fixed size (say, 200x200px) rectangle? Is it a percentage of `Bitmap.Width` (e.g. 20% width)? You will probably have `var topLeftRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, something, something);`, followed by `var topLeftBitmap = b.Clone(topLeftRect, b.PixelFormat);`.

Comment: @Groo yes it is a fixed rectangle - is it possible to just scan a file in just that rectangle size on a page/file

Comment: @BB987: as I wrote, you should load the entire file into a `Bitmap` like you're already doing, and then use `b.Clone` to extract separate `Bitmap`s.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to try:

1. Filter the files by extensions, as suggested by Carra
2. Declare and instantiate `QRCodeDecoder` only once
3. Append the text using `StringBuilder` and assign it only once

It would be something like that:

```
private void ScanQRPdf(string imagePath)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles ( path, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories );

    QRCodeDecoder decoder = new QRCodeDecoder();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var item in files)
    {

            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(imagePath);
            try
            {
                String decodedString = decoder.decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(b));

                sb.AppendLine(decodedString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

    }

    rtbpdfData.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

But I really do not think it will solve your problem, that's all minor enhancements and your delay must be somewhere within the `QRCodeDecoder` and `QRCodeBitmapImage` class, specifically in the `decode` method, you should try to understand them better, and find out what it is internally doing so you can improve your code.

Comment: I don't think such recommendations should be made without profiling. In this case, I am pretty sure that the `decode` method takes at least 95% of the execution time.

Comment: I just tried it out and ya it is still kind of slow. I am wondering if i could only scan/check a corner of the page for the qr code if that will cut down on time. The QR code will always be on the top left corner and if i don't find it i will rotate the page and check. Does that sound something doable?

Comment: Yes it is doable, though you will have to find how to slice the pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GetFiles with a type:

```
string[ ] files = Directory.GetFiles ( path, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories );
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the bottleneck.

Comment: You're right, it's probably a small improvement, depends on the amount of files. But the bottleneck is probably in the decoder and we can't see that part.